# cannot authenticate user for aws appsync with swift SDK

Tags: swift, xcode, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

I am trying to connect to my AWS AppSync service from my Swift mobile app using the AWS Swift SDK but keep getting the following error:

```
Error occurred: (401 unauthorized) Did not receive a successful HTTP code.
```

I am using User Pools and have set everything up following the tutorial for swift.  My question is, how do I incorporate the AppSync.json config file generated in the console in my request?  That is not mentioned in the tutorial and may be the reason I cannot connect.

The json file looks like this:

```
{
    "graphqlEndpoint": "my_endpoint_url",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "authenticationType": "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
    "apiKey": null
}
```

At the moment I am using the following configuration:

```
// Set up  Amazon Cognito credentials
let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: CognitoIdentityRegion,
                                                        identityPoolId: CognitoIdentityPoolId, identityProviderManager: pool)
// You can choose your database location, accessible by SDK
let databaseURL = URL(fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(database_name)

do {
    // Initialize the AWS AppSync configuration

    let appSyncConfig = try AWSAppSyncClientConfiguration(url: AppSyncEndpointURL,
                                                          serviceRegion: AppSyncRegion,
                                                          credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider,
                                                          databaseURL:databaseURL)

    appSyncClient = try AWSAppSyncClient(appSyncConfig: appSyncConfig)
    // Set id as the cache key for objects
    appSyncClient?.apolloClient?.cacheKeyForObject = { $0["id"] }
} catch {
    print("Error initializing appsync client. \(error)")
}
```

EDIT #1

It turns out the example is using the API key method rather than user pools.  So now I have changed the config to:

```
let appSyncConfig = try AWSAppSyncClientConfiguration(url: AppSyncEndpointURL, serviceRegion: AppSyncRegion, userPoolsAuthProvider: CognitoUserPoolsAuthProvider(pool: pool))
```

The problem is the message now is:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'CognitoUserPoolsAuthProvider'
```

if I try:

```
let appSyncConfig = try AWSAppSyncClientConfiguration(url: AppSyncEndpointURL, serviceRegion: AppSyncRegion, userPoolsAuthProvider: AWSCognitoUserPoolsAuthProvider(pool: pool))
```

the error is:

```
'AWSCognitoUserPoolsAuthProvider' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
```

Not sure how to satisfy the userPoolsAuthProvider: argument in the config.

Answer (score 1):

To address your specific issue, `userPoolsAuthProvider` needs to accept a class that extends the `AWSCognitoUserPoolsAuthProvider` protocol. So your instantiation would look something like this:

```
 let appSyncConfig = try AWSAppSyncClientConfiguration(url: AppSyncEndpointURL,
                                                          serviceRegion: AppSyncRegion,
                                                          userPoolsAuthProvider: self,
                                                          databaseURL:databaseURL)
```

And then in the class in which you are creating the AppSyncClient, you would extend like this:

```
extension YourClass: AWSCognitoUserPoolsAuthProvider {
  func getLatestAuthToken() -> String {
    var token: String = ""

    // pool is an instance of AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool
    self.pool?.currentUser()?.getSession().continueOnSuccessWith(block: { (task) -> Any? in 
      token = task.result!.idToken!.tokenString
      return nil
    }).waitUnitFinished()
  }

  return token
}
```

Also I *think* the AppSync configuration by default looks for an `awsconfiguration.json` file in your project. You posted this a while back so possibly things have changed with AWS services and AppSync.

Hope this helps

Comment: the .waitUntilFinished blocks the main thread.  it causes significant lagging of the app occasionally and debugger warnings.  also you need to unwrap your optional token in the code you posted and if it's nil that will cause a crash.

Comment: All true statements. But hopefully this helped you get further