# How to authenicate AWS Appsync in iOS (Swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-appsync

Junior developer here.

I'm trying to get AWS Appsync to work in an iOS app I'm currently building, but I cant get authentication working.

I want to replicate this Javascript code in swift, for my authenication.

```
Amplify.configure({

Auth: {

region: "<REGION>",

userPoolId: "<USER-POOL-ID>",

userPoolWebClientId: "<USER-POOL-WEB-CLIENT-ID>"

}

});

const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({

auth: {

jwtToken: async () =>

(await Auth.currentSession()).getIdToken().getJwtToken(),

type: AUTH_TYPE.AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS

},

disableOffline: true,

region: "<REGION>",

url:

"<ENDPOINT-URL>"

});
```

I have found a similar problem here:
[cannot authenticate user for aws appsync with swift SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49204014/cannot-authenticate-user-for-aws-appsync-with-swift-sdk/51476402#51476402)

But he hasn't gotten an answer.

I have googled plenty but cant seem to find a solution. 
Could one of you kind programer souls point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS SDK for iOS - AppSync solves your use-case. You can check out the documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/building-a-client-app-ios.html. You can check out the source code here: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-ios. There is a starter app which will help you onboard quickly: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-mobile-appsync-events-starter-ios.

```
import UIKit
import AWSAppSync

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

   var window: UIWindow?
   var appSyncClient: AWSAppSyncClient?

   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       // Set up Amazon Cognito credentials
       let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: CognitoIdentityRegion,
                                                               identityPoolId: CognitoIdentityPoolId)
       // You can choose your database location, accessible by the SDK
       let databaseURL = URL(fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(database_name)

       do {
           // Initialize the AWS AppSync configuration
           let appSyncConfig = try AWSAppSyncClientConfiguration(url: AppSyncEndpointURL,
                                                                 serviceRegion: AppSyncRegion,
                                                                 credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider,
                                                                 databaseURL:databaseURL)
           // Initialize the AWS AppSync client
           appSyncClient = try AWSAppSyncClient(appSyncConfig: appSyncConfig)
           // Set id as the cache key for objects
           appSyncClient?.apolloClient?.cacheKeyForObject = { $0["id"] }
       } catch {
           print("Error initializing appsync client. \(error)")
       }
       return true
   }

   // ... other intercept methods
}
```